# Skyrim Greybeards Location

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do you get to the 1000 steps where the Greybeards are from Whiterun.  I tried with the map, but I ended up in several bandit camps.

I also ran into this very annoying camp where several bandits had magic and bow which could get me from a longer distance.  I am a melee orc.  I almost died if it wasn't for my follower Jennessa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The entrance to the Thousand Steps is on the southeast side of the Greybeards' quest marker, in the town of Ivarstead. I got there by working my way south around the east side of the mountain from Whiterun (and slaughtering my way through a few bandits).

(You should also be able to get there by working your way east-and-a-little-south from Riverwood until you hit a road, and follow the road east to Ivarstead, but I haven't traveled that exact path myself.)

And if that isn't enough help, try using [this map](http://tamrielma.ps/skyrim/) to plan your route.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to travel to Ivarstead which is right at the bottom of the mountain,it is also south of whiterun. You end up going to this location during the dark brother hood quest line. [image]
It can also be found far to the West of Riften

Answer (score 0):

Three routes spring to mind :

1) From Whiterun - go south to riverwood - and then to Helgen. If you creep around helgen you should be able to get to Ivarstead safely - but that is risky. Don't go through Helgen though.

2) From Whiterun - follow the main road to the north of the "Throat of the world" - If you stay on the main road, you should only meet one encamped set of bandits - in the tower - and there is a path over the mountain which you can use to avoid them, although that could be more risky. You might meet one or more bandit teams, or wild animals on the main road, but they should be levelled and beatable.

3) From Riften - catch the coach to Riften, and walk from there. but I guess that route will have the same bandit issues.

If you have Dawnguard DLC enabled, then you will also face random vampire attacks - I find that a ranged weapon (bow & arrow, or a magic staff) is the best strategy here. If you try to melee them they can be very very difficult, even when they are levelled to you (which all random attacks should be).